# How do I hide/show ng-bootstrap datepicker-popup?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How do I hide or show the **ng-bootstrap** [datepicker-popup](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/df6d33ddc1a8d02d16d874f192e7848f64295293/demo/src/app/components/datepicker/demos/popup/datepicker-popup.html) with a property which I can set to 'true' or 'false'?

I'm using the following form snippet in a form. I want to display the whole `div` session only if the user wants to enter a Date Of Birth (DOB). To set DOB or not is decided via radio buttons.

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="dobId"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="dob" value="dob" id="dobId" />Enter DOB</label>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="nodobId"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="nodob" value="dob" id="nodobId" />Ignore DOB</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <fieldset class="form-group col-6">
        <legend class="col-form-legend" for="dateOfBirthId">Date Of Birth</legend>
        <ngbd-datepicker-popup id="dateOfBirthId"></ngbd-datepicker-popup>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the forms technique (Template Driven or Reactive Forms) to get the value of your selection. In Template Driven, import the NgForm from @angular/forms and use the form tag in the view. Your radio button should have unique value. Use *ngIf to check the value and you can show/hide the date picker.